# .REGEXP_REPLACE for add value in columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add 'Shri_' to First_name of the customer table, only for the names which don't have 'Mr_' in the begining. Data of customer table is as shown below:

[image]

I am using below script but It doesn't help.

```
update customers set first_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name,'^(?!Mr_)(.*)', 'Shri_\2',1,1);
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong in my regex. To be more specific, I am trying to find out correct Regex for this case.

Answer (score 7):

Regex is quite complex; you can solve this more simply by:

```
UPDATE customers 
SET first_name = 'Shri_' || first_name 
WHERE first_name NOT LIKE 'Mr\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

I suspect the problem was the _ being a wildcard but it can be escaped like above, so it no longer means "any single char" but instead just "underscore"

Comment: Yes +1, and I would add that Oracle regex does support lookarounds, so this is probably the best option here.

Comment: Yes great answer +1 for this, But my ask is more specifically on how to build regex in this case.

Comment: Strictly speaking, according to your first sentence of your question, your ask was simply to add 'Mr_' without damaging 'Mritunjay' - it didn't say it had to be done with regex replace ;) and indeed its a bit of an XY problem; your proposed solution has trouble but it should perhaps be the original problem you seek to solve not the trouble with the proposed solution. Any reason why you're determined not to use a WHERE clause? REGEXP_LIKE could make your life simpler!

Comment: Because I already know about it, I am trying to explore more about using Regex in Oracle. But Regex given online doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question then, more like "why doesn't this regex XXX change this data YYY so it says ZZZ"?